# Yarn requires Node.js 4.0 or higher and not executing scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to start the server, but when I enter the command **yarn run dev** gives
Yarn requires Node.js 4.0 or higher to be installed.
I installed the latest available version of NodeJs, but nothing has changed. I also entered the command
**npm install -g yarn**, but nothing worked either. How else can you solve this problem?

Comment: What happens when you type `yarn`?

Comment: `node -v` probably still reads the same version, I'm guessing. On windows try `where node` or on Unix `which node`. That will tell you the order of the resolved executables located on your machine, if you have multiple installed, which it sounds like you do.

Comment: I had a similar issue on Ubuntu where running `yarn install` worked, but running `sudo yarn install` gave me that error message about Node.js 4.0. I resolved it by updating the `PATH` for sudo. (Actually I just removed the binary that `sudo which yarn` identified, but that is hacky and it would be better to fix the sudo `PATH`.) See my full question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59018953/3287963

Answer (score 2):

If the NVM already installed, try at the terminal
$ source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh